# Delete user stored temp records from DB when automatically session timeout using Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two tables (`tb_access_log_table` and `tb_session`). `tb_access_log_table` records will be cleared once session automatically expired using `Zend Framework`.

I'm new to `Zend Framework`. How should I do this?

I dont know how to call another (`tb_access_log_table`) into session `read($id)` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go about this with a script set to run at a regular interval using CRON.  Have it find the sessions that have expired on tb_session and use whatever FK associates records on tb_access_log_table to purge those records.

Ensuring execution of some code based callback per expired session is not going to be reliable.